# I have problems with getting numbers from the file. Function fscanf reads only strings. 8

Tags: c, input, scanf

Fscanf does not work and I can't understand why. It only reads strings and nothing else. 
1 2 3 is written in the file.txt. 
Here's the code:

```
include<stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    FILE* ptr = fopen("file.txt","r"); 

    if (ptr==NULL) 
    { 
        printf("no such file."); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    char* buf[100]; 
    int a;

    fscanf(ptr," %d ",a);
        printf("%d\n", a); 
    fscanf(ptr," %s ",buf);

        printf("%s\n", buf); 



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There should be pointer to `a` (so the function knows *where* to store the read integer value) - `fscanf(ptr, "%d", &a)`

Comment: Thank you. However even after doing so the function does not put anything in a.

Comment: `int result = fscanf(ptr,"%d ",&a);
        printf("Number of scanned items: %d. A = %d\n", result, a);` always check the scanf result

Comment: also your buf should be declared as **char buf[100];**

Comment: _"Fscanf does not work..."_.  You should apply Occam's Razor to such situations - clearly `fscanf()` _does work_ and the problem is in your code rather than with `fscanf()`.  If the content applied to the %d format specifier _is not_ a decimal numeric string, no conversion will be performed and `a` will remain unchanged.   Since whitespace is a default delimiter for `fscanf()`, there is no need to include it in the format string.

Comment: Note that `char* buf[100];`isn´t a pointer to a `char` array calles `buf`. It is a array of pointers called `buf`. You should declare the `char` array as `char buf[100];` and address a pointer to that separate like `char *p; p = buf;`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your provided code, I would like to first talk about before getting to the answer you have asked for.

#### 1.

```
fscanf(ptr," %d ",a);
```

This is false. Here the address of an `int` is needed as third argument. You need the ampersand operator `&` to access an address of a variable, like:

```
fscanf(ptr," %d ",&a);
```

#### 2.

```
fscanf(ptr," %s ",buf);
```

Is also false. A pointer to a `char` array is needed here as third argument, but `buf` is declared as an array of 100 pointers after

```
char* buf[100];
```

You need to declare `buf` in the right way as a `char` array, like:

```
char buf[100];
```

to make it work with:

```
fscanf(ptr," %s ",buf);
```

#### 3.

You have forgot the `#` in the include directive for `stdio.h`:

```
include<stdio.h>
```

Also, there should be a white space gap between `#include` and the file you want to include.

So the preprocessor directive should be look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

#### 4.

If the open stream operation fails you should not use `return` with a value of `0`.

If an operation fails, that is crucial to the program itself, the return value of the program should be a non-zero value (the value of `1` is the most common) or `EXIT_FAILURE`(which is a macro designed for that purpose (defined in header `<stdlib.h>`)), not `0`, which indicating to outer software applications as well as the operation system, that a problem has occurred and the program could not been executed successfully as it was ment for its original purpose.

So use:

```
if (ptr==NULL) 
{ 
    printf("no such file."); 
    return 1; 
}
```

#### 5.

> Fscanf does not work and I can't understand why. It only reads strings and nothing else.

What did you expect as result? What do you want that `fscanf()`should do?

The format specifier `%s` is used to read strings until the first occurrence of a white space character in the input stream (skips leading white space characters until the matching sequence is encountered), pointed to by `ptr`.

---

Then I get from your header title:

> I have problems with getting numbers from the file

that you want only the numbers from the file.

If you want to get the numbers only from the text file, you do not need the `char` array `buf` and the whole things with reading strings at all.

Simply use something like:

```
int a,b,c;            // buffer integers.
fscanf(ptr,"%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
```

Of course, this expressions implying that it only work with the given example of the `1 2 3` data or anything equivalent to `(integer) (integer) (integer)` but I think you get the idea of how it works.

And, of course, you can apply the scan operation by using `fscanf()` (and also the print operation by using `printf()`) for each integer separate in a loop, instead to scan/print all integers with just one call to `fscanf()` and `printf()`, f.e. like:

```
#define Integers_in_File 3

int array[Integers_in_File];

for(int i = 0; i < Integers_in_File; i++)
{
     fscanf(ptr,"%d",&array[i]);     // writing to respective int buffers, 
}                                    // provided as elements of an int array.

for(int i = 0; i < Integers_in_File; i++)
{
     printf("%d",array[i]);          // Output the scanned integers from 
}                                    // the file.
```

---

The whole program would be than either:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    FILE* ptr = fopen("file.txt","r"); 

    if (ptr==NULL) 
    { 
        printf("no such file."); 
        return 1; 
    } 

    int a,b,c;            // buffer integers.
    fscanf(ptr,"%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);

    printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);                                  

    return 0;
}
```

Or that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Integers_in_File 3 

int main() 
{ 
    int array[Integers_in_File];

    FILE* ptr = fopen("file.txt","r"); 

    if (ptr==NULL) 
    { 
        printf("no such file."); 
        return 1; 
    } 

    for(int i = 0; i < Integers_in_File; i++)
    {
        fscanf(ptr," %d",&array[i]);     // writing to respective intbuffers, 
    }                                    // provided as elements of an int  
                                         // array.

    for(int i = 0; i < Integers_in_File; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",array[i]);          // Output the scanned integers from 
    }                                   // the file.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed the code.
```
void entry( FILE *ptr)
{
 double n;
 while(fscanf(ptr," %lg ",&n) != EOF)
    {
  insert(n);
    }
}
```
```
if (argc<2) 
   error(3);
 if ((ptr = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) 
   error(4);
 entry(ptr);
```
The problem was with the compiler. The first three characters of the file always were junk.
Everything works perfectly in Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @SvyatoslavEfremov Don´t forget to mark this answer as accepted one, if it solved your problem or was the most helpful one.

Answer (score 2):

- The variadic arguments to `fscanf()` must be pointers.
- Whitespace is the default delimiter and need not be included in the format string.
- If the input stream does not match the format specifier, the content remains buffered, and the argument is not assigned.  You should therefore check the conversion which can fail due to mismatching content or EOF.
- To declare an array for a character string, the array type must be `char` not `char*` - that would be an array of pointers, not an array of characters.

```
    char buf[100]; 
    int a;

    if( fscanf( ptr, "%d", &a ) > 0 )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", a ) ; 
        if( fscanf(ptr, "%s", buf) > 0 )
        {
            printf( "%s\n", buf ) ;
        }
    }
```

Or simply:

```
char buf[100]; 
int a;

if( fscanf( ptr, "%d%s", &a, buff ) == 2 )
{
    printf( "%d\n", a ) ; 
    printf( "%s\n", buf ) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed the code.
```
void entry( FILE *ptr)
{
 double n;
 while(fscanf(ptr," %lg ",&n) != EOF)
    {
  insert(n);
    }
}
```
```
if (argc<2) 
   error(3);
 if ((ptr = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) 
   error(4);
 entry(ptr);
```
The problem was with the compiler. The first three chatacters of the file always were junk.
Everything works perfectly in Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @SvyatoslavEfremov Recall what I said about Occam's Razor? The same applies here - the compiler is the least likely thing to be at fault, if your code generated an invalid file, then it is near certain that it is your code at fault.  Don't post code in comments, and your comment about working in the shell but not in the compiler makes no sense.  Do you mean an IDE rather than _compiler_?  The compiler has no relevance to the runtime environment.

Comment: I worked in Mobile C on my phone. Then I switched to laptop and code started working.

Comment: @SvyatoslavEfremov The code in the question was just incorrect - regardless if the compiler,, and that has been answered. Why "correct" code might work in one compiler and not another us a different question, not to be dealt with in comments.